# Domain name under different account than hosting

Tags: domains

I've tried to do some research on pointing a domain name to hosting that's on two separate accounts, but either I haven't found the right article. Or I'm missing some steps somewhere.

Both accounts are thru Go Daddy. One is the client's which they have bought a dozen domains on relating to their business, which all forward to the primary one I want to link to the hosting on my own account. The second account is my own (where I host my personal website and domain names) & I purchased a separate hosting plan for the client since they do not want the hosting under their own account.

There's stuff on the web & godaddy that states I just need to change the "Nameservers" on their domain name to the nameservers on my domain name attached to the hosting. However, these happen to be the exact same (since they are both hosted by godaddy). It's just some generic ns##.domaincontrol.com.

So what else do I need to do to get their domain to identify with my hosting?

Comment: "pointing a domain name to hosting that's on two separate accounts" - not sure what you mean by that? One domain can only point to one account? "...since they do **not** want the hosting under their own account" - Should that "not" be there?!

Answer (score 1):

With GoDaddy, your options are 'Domain Forwarding', 'Domain Pointing' and 'Addon Domains'.

In any scenario, you will need a folder to act as the domain root (you've already done this.) and the server IP of the hosting you've setup.

To [Forward a domain](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422), 
If you want to **forward a domain**, go to Domain -> Settings -> Forwarding.

You will be prompted to follow a simple wizard, where you can pick where and how you display other content. You will probably want to use the 'Masked Forwarding' option to keep your client's URL in the address bar.

**Pointing a domain** is basically just manually updating the A-record.
To [Point a domain](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-for-your-domain-names-680) to another host, edit the A-record in the DNS settings.  and set the IP for '@' to your hosting IP.

[image: arecord]

With both the above methods, you will need an .htaccess file that redirects traffic from clienturl.com to clientfolder/127.0.0.1  (but your real IP.) Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clienturl\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.clienturl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ clientfolder [L]
```

That brings us to [addon domains](https://www.godaddy.com/help/adding-addon-domains-to-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account-8877). If you set up a subdomain/**addon domain** on the hosting server, you will not have to setup an .htaccess file. You will be able to forward the client domain from their server, directly to a subdomain on your server, without having to rely on .htaccess.

Your server will handle the mapping of the subdomain to the client folder. So, clienturl.com will forward to myclient.myhostip.com, which will map to  /myhost/myclient/  on your server.

hope some of this makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters. Really thorough answer with great resources!